# Django not hitting Class Views on Form post

Tags: python, django, forms, post, django-class-based-views

In my views for some reason it skips the the `CheckbackView` class based view and rerenders the same page, With my Empty form.

**thunderdome/Views**

```
class SquirrelView(View):
    def post (self, request):
        form = request.POST.get("thundersubmit", "")
        if form  == '1':
            request.session["_thundersubmit"] = 'Pool'
            return HttpResponseRedirect('Bartertown')
        if form  == '2':
            request.session["_thundersubmit"] = 'Paste'
            return HttpResponseRedirect('Bartertown')
        if form  == '3':
            request.session["_thundersubmit"] = 'Upload'
            return HttpResponseRedirect('Bartertown')


        return HttpResponseRedirect('home')

def Bartertown(request):
    statusly = request.session.get('_thundersubmit')
    print statusly
    if statusly == 'Paste':
        render(request, 'thunderdome/paste_form.html')
    return HttpResponse(statusly)

class CheckbackView(View):
    print 'Hello - Fom Checkback'
    def post(self, request):
        return HttpResponse('Ha!')
```

^^^ **Skips the `CheckbackView`post view completely and re-renders the same page with the empty form, instead of `return HttpResponse('Ha!')` .**

**Urls**

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from app.forms import BootstrapAuthenticationForm
from thunderdome.views import SquirrelView, Bartertown, CheckbackView

# Uncomment the next lines to enable the admin:
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'app.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^contact$', 'app.views.contact', name='contact'),
    url(r'^about', 'app.views.about', name='about'),
    url(r'^Thunderdome', include('thunderdome.urls')),
    url(r'^Thunderdome/squirrel', SquirrelView.as_view()),
    url(r'^Thunderdome/Bartertown', 'thunderdome.views.Bartertown'),
    url(r'^Thunderdome/Bartertown/checkback', CheckbackView.as_view()),
```

**thunderdome/paste_form.html**

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="/Thunderdome/Bartertown/checkback/" method="POST">

<fieldset>
    <legend>Paste-A-Config</legend>


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Paste here..." rows="25" name="ConfigSubmit"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>


<div class="form-actions">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                Cancel
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
                Submit
            </button>
```

WSGI side:

```
[Mon Feb 09 08:48:50 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.3 mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

**Why is this happening?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to terminate your URL regexes. `r'^Thunderdome/Bartertown'` also matches "Thunderdome/Bartertown/anythingyoulike", and this includes your "checkback" URL. You should always terminate the patterns:

```
url(r'^Thunderdome/squirrel/$', SquirrelView.as_view()),
url(r'^Thunderdome/Bartertown/$', 'thunderdome.views.Bartertown'),
url(r'^Thunderdome/Bartertown/checkback/$', CheckbackView.as_view()),
```

Comment: That moment of shame when you find out you're an idiot for not doing this already.